# MySQL ORDER BY on a thread-based message system

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a message system where users can send messages to each other. It's thread-based like in Facebook. So every user should be in only one specific message-thread with another single user.

The main overview of all messages isn't working as I want it to be. It only shows the oldest (first) message text and date of a thread and doesn't sort by latest message sent.

---

The MySQL database structure:

`messages_assign`: `id`,`uid`,`thread_id`,`status`,`date`

`messages_content`: `id`,`uid`,`thread_id`,`text`,`date`

`messages_thread`: `id`,`creator_uid`,`receiver_uid`

---

I think it's self-explanatory, but to clarify: `messages_assign` assigns the content(s) to a specific message thread. I want to expand this message system to be able to send messages to multiple users someday, that's why I came up with this structure.

---

This is my MySQL query in PHP:

```
    $menu = mysql_query("SELECT 
    t.`id`, t.`creator_uid`,
    c.`uid` AS content_uid, c.`text`, c.`date` AS content_date,
    a.`status`, a.`date` AS assign_date,
    CASE 
    WHEN t.`creator_uid`='".sInput($_SESSION['uid'])."' THEN `receiver_uid`
    WHEN t.`receiver_uid`='".sInput($_SESSION['uid'])."' THEN `creator_uid`
    END AS uid
    FROM `messages_content` c
    LEFT JOIN `messages_thread` t ON t.`id` = c.`thread_id`
    LEFT JOIN `messages_assign` a ON a.`id` = t.`id`
    WHERE 
    t.`creator_uid`='".sInput($_SESSION['uid'])."' 
    OR 
    t.`receiver_uid`='".sInput($_SESSION['uid'])."' 
    GROUP BY t.`id` 
    ORDER BY c.`id` DESC") or die (mysql_error());
```

I guess that there has to be a sub-query somewhere to let it sort by the latest date and text, but I'm not familiar with that and also wouldn't know where to put that and how?

So basically I just want that the message threads are sorted by the latest message received, showing the latest text and date of a specific thread.